# Scraping a number within from text using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to separate a number from within a span (Code Below). I used class to find my information on the page because the page doesn't have id's to the specific information I want to gather, so it gives me the entire line of HTML code. I want to be able to separate the number in this instance from the rest of the information. I already have done so with the title, and thought I could use a similar method to do so with the price.

When I print the title I get: Bridgestone Corporation (BRDCY)

When I print the price I get: `<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">18.58</span>`

How can I extract the 18.58 so that is the only string/int set to price?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRDCY?p=BRDCY&.tsrc=fin-srch'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="Lead-3-QuoteHeader-Proxy").get_text()
price = soup.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")


#price = price[price.find(">"), price.find("<")]
title = title[0:title.find(")")+1]

print(price)
print(title)
```

Comment: `print(price.text)`.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this? This is a very basic question, have you read the documentation? I’m voting to close this, as these kinds of questions are of very little value to both the asker and future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get_text() function as you have used for Title

```
  price = soup.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I thought I did try that but I must've of typed something wrong the first time. Much appreciated